# How to prove $\text{Con}(PA + \text{Con}(PA))$ in $ZFC$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms

How to prove $\text{Con}(PA + \text{Con}(PA))$ in $ZFC$?

I found an example of this claim [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/50174/2003) but I'm looking for a more detailed explanation.

An equivalent statement is: there is no proof in $PA$ that $PA$ is inconsistent.

If $PA$ could prove that $PA$ is inconsistent, then $ZFC$ could also prove it, so $ZFC$ would be inconsistent (because $ZFC$ also proves that $PA$ *is* consistent).  But that's not a contradiction since we can't prove that $ZFC$ is consistent anyway (in $ZFC$).

Is there a theory $T$ intermediate in consistency strength, so that $ZFC$ proves that $T$ is consistent and $T$ proves that $PA$ is consistent?  That would solve the problem with the above approach (since $PA$ proving its own inconsistency would make $T$ inconsistent which would make a contradiction in $ZFC$).

Comment: Since ZFC proves "PA is consistent", some finitely axiomatizable subtheory of ZFC proves "PA is consistent". Call that finitely axiomatizable subtheory T. Then T proves that PA is consistent, and ZFC proves that T is consistent. Leastways I think it does. That's something I seem to recall learning a long time ago, that ZFC proves the consistency of its finitely axiomatizable subtheories. I could be wrong.

Comment: @bof Yes, for any finite fragment of ZFC, ZFC proves that it is consistent. This follows from the reflection principle but I don't know if there is an easier way to see it.

Comment: ZFC proves the consistency of Zermelo set theory (i.e., ZFC without the axiom of replacement) by a straightforward construction of the set $V_{\omega+\omega}$ that provides a model for Zermelo in the von Neumann hierarchy. Zermelo is much stronger than PA.

Comment: Instead of raising a huge bounty, it could be nice to get some comments and interactions on the current answers where you point out what is possibly missing from them. But have it your way. Good luck.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't interact with the people who posted answers, letting them know directly what you feel is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The completeness theorem for first-order logic tells us that a theory $T$ is consistent if and only it has a model. Moreover, since $\sf ZFC$ proves the completeness theorem, in order to show that $\sf PA+\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ is consistent, we just need to show it has a model.

But this is not quite what you are asking for. Since $\sf\operatorname{Con}(PA+\operatorname{Con}(PA))$ is a statement about arithmetic, we need to code these things into the natural numbers first.

Luckily, all the usual coding schemes work just fine. So that means that for a theory $T$ with Godel coding, $\sf ZFC$ proves that $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ holds in the natural numbers, if and only if $T$ has a model.

Now, since $\sf PA$ is true in $\omega$, we get that $\sf PA$ is consistent and therefore $\operatorname{Con}\sf (PA)$ is true in $\omega$, and therefore $\sf PA+\operatorname{Con}(PA)$ is true there. So we found a model for our theory, and therefore $\sf\operatorname{Con}(PA+\operatorname{Con}(PA))$ is provable from $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: I don't fully understand the downvote. Is it because I complained about setting the bounty without interacting with the existing answers? Is it that my answer is unhelpful, and if so, in what way?

Comment: My idea of how this is supposed to work is something like this: first we define some computable function mapping the formulas of PA to $\omega$.  Then, it is possible to define a predicate on $\omega$ corresponding to arithmetical truth -- this part is a bit murky, but I think I would proceed by first proving the base case of unquantified formulas and then try to handle quantifiers recursively.  So, say we've defined this set of integers corresponding to true formulas.  The axioms of PA are in this set, all of the inference rules preserve membership in this set, ...

Comment: the set is nonempty, so PA is consistent, and we can prove all that in ZFC.  And we can also show Con(PA) is in this set, so that establishes Con(PA+Con(PA)).

Comment: The parts that are not clear to me are how exactly to define the set of true formulas, and also why Con(PA) is in that set.  Also if that is roughly correct I'd like to understand the relationship to model theory concepts. @Asaf

Comment: Okay. I'm travelling right now, but I'll be home by the weekend. If nobody addressed these issues, I'll try to elaborate according to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in ZFC there is a model of PA + Con(PA), namely the natural numbers. Also the soundness  theorem (if a theory has a model, it is consistent) is a theorem in ZFC so it is also a theorem of ZFC that the above is consistent.

Edit: I think I understand your approach now. But I don't think it could lead to anything. The problem is that PA+Con(PA) is already a somehow minimal form of such a theory T you are looking for (of course there are way weaker theories that would do it but I don't think they would make anything easier).

Comment: I don't understand model theory very well and that is likely part of my trouble.  For the second part yes $PA + \text{Con}(PA)$ is just such a theory so I guess my attempt is just a reformulation of the question.  I have read that $\text{Con}(PA)$ can be proved in Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, so I was thinking can $\text{Con}(PRA)$ be formulated and proved in $ZFC$?

Comment: If a structure satisfies some theory (i.e. all of its formulas are true in it), then the theory must be consistent. The reason is simple: any provable statement must be true in the structure, in particular if the theory is inconsistent then statements $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ must be true in the structure which can't happen.

Comment: @Dan: The consistency of $\sf PA$ can be proved from $\sf PRA$ ***with*** induction up to $\varepsilon_0$. Not just $\sf PRA$ which is a very weak fragment of $\sf PA$ itself.